# Assembly: Jumping Confusion

Tags: function, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I'm using the Irvine32.inc library, and am having an issue with my `L4` jump.

```
    L1:
    mov edx, offset optionPromptMsg
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    mov ebx, 1
    cmp eax, ebx
    je L2                    //if eax is 1, jump to l2, if eax is -1, jump l3
    mov ebx, -1
    cmp eax, ebx
    je L3
    mov ebx, -2
    mov ecx, 2
    cmp ebx, eax   //if eax is less than -2 or more than 2 jump to L4
    ja L4
    cmp eax, ecx
    ja L4
    L2: call NextScore

    L4: mov edx, offset optionErrorMsg
        call WriteString

    loop L1
    L3 : call WriteScore
```

No matter how I format it, for some reason everytime `L2: call NextScore` is called, immediantly afterward `L4` is called and I can't figure out why. `NextScore` is as follows...

```
NextScore PROC USES esi

mov edx, offset scorePromptMsg
call WriteString
call ReadInt
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, 100
cmp ebx, eax
ja L1
cmp eax,ecx
ja L1
jmp L2
L1:
    mov edx, offset scoreErrorMsg
    call WriteString
L2:
    mov scores[esi*4], eax
    inc esi

ret
NextScore ENDP
```

As you see, `NextScore` reads in a value from 0-100 then, unsuccessfully at this time, adds that value to an array `scores`. For some reason it only adds duplicates of one number throughout the entire array,but that's an entirely different issue. Any thoughts or ideas are most appreciated!

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem correctly, but you are aware that `ret` will return to after the `call`, so in this case `L4`?

Comment: @Jester `L4` is being called when I don't want it to be, say for example, `L2` is called, I enter a number, then directly after that `L4` is called for some reason and I'm not sure why. And I think what you just said sounds like it would help, if you would elaborate a bit. So the `ret` in `NextScore` returns to where exactly?

Comment: It returns exactly to `L4` because every `ret` goes back to where the matching `call` was. That is if you want to do something else, you need to add code before `L4` that gets executed when `NextScore` returns (such as a `jmp` to wherever you want to go instead of `L4)`.

Comment: @Jester perfect! Thanks for explaining that, it helped immensely. Make it as an answer to my question so I can upvote/choose your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ret` at the end of `NextScore` goes back exactly to `L4` because every `ret` goes back to continue where the matching `call` left off. That is if you want to do something else, you need to add code before `L4` that gets executed when `NextScore` returns (such as a `jmp` to wherever you want to go instead of `L4`):